# Navigate from one php file to another carrying array of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a requirement where there is a file display.php, here this file will display a form with searched data.
Now in that form I have a Edit button and onclick of this button I need to carry those form data which is in the array structure and I need to fill that form with this data.

display.php

```
$customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
$returnData = "";

$datas = mysql_query("SELECT customer_name, customer_email, customer_phone, customer_address FROM dataform WHERE customer_id = '".$customer_id."'");
$data = mysql_fetch_row($datas);
$labels = array("Name : ","Email : ","Phone : ", "Address : ");
for ($x = 0; $x < count($data); $x++) {
    $returnData .= "<div class=\"form-group\">
                    <label class=\"col-md-2 control-label\" for=\"inputName\">".$labels[$x]."</label>  
                    <div class=\"col-md-4\" style=\"padding-top: 8px;\">"
                    .$data[$x].
                    "</div>
                    </div>";
}
$returnData .= "<div class=\"form-group\">
                <label class=\"col-md-2 control-label\" for=\"buttonSubmit\"></label>
                <div class=\"col-md-8\">
                <button id=\"buttonSubmit\" name=\"buttonSubmit\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" onclick=\"clickEdit(".'["' . implode('", "', $data) . '"]'.");\">Edit</button>
                </div>
                </div>";
echo $returnData;
```

In the above code there is a line which creates a Button called Edit and here in this button i have a onclick() event.
On click of this button I need to carry $data to one more form that is already created where it is used to create the data.

Please have a look into pictorial representation of my requirement in this link http://postimg.org/image/t1xo84vo7/.

Thanks,

--Darshan D

Comment: As per you link it seems like simple update operation which you are making more complicated. Dont pass $Data, pass $customer_id to your url on edit button and then fetch the $data using same query u listed above in displayform.php . Pass data to form and do edit. You are making things complicated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In display.php you can put the array data in json on a input hidden element and send it in the javascript function (you need to send the input value).

Also you can use base64 to encode the json value for better manipulation.

Then in dataform.php you should use base64_decode() and json_decode() and then you can use the array.

Or just pass the data:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_row($datas);
$tosend = base64_encode(json_encode($data));

...

$returnData .= '<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="buttonSubmit"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <button id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clickEdit("'.$tosend.'");">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>';
```

Then on server just:

```
$array = json_decode(base64_decode($received_var));
```

> Remember to use ' instead of " if you dont need evaluate the entire chain.

-- ADDED --

On your onClick function maybe you can use:

```
function clickEdit(data){
     window.location.href = "path_to_url/dataform.php?userdata="+data;
}
```

But the best method is what it says @Anand Ghaywankar "pass $customer_id
to your url on edit button and then fetch the $data using same query u
listed above in displayform.php", but this can work.

If you want to use the method of @Anand Ghaywankar you only need set the user_id into your onClick and send it. Then on the server you must load user data with the same query you used in display.php as says @Anand

BR.

Comment: If you don't use base64_encode and pass only json array, you can recive and use the array data in your javascript function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, infact it was best one. Please could you tell me or write a function how can i navigate onclick (handling the onclick event).

Comment: Thanks this approch helped me to carry data view files later get into access the data recived.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to carry data between pages.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But how can I navigate from this to another page by triggering onclick() event. Also where should i want to handle that onclick event on Edit button (in search.php file or here in display.php file).

Comment: Do you really need an onclick() event? Use a simple <a> link or submit a form to go to a different page.

Comment: yes i can use anchor tag but how can i send data on navigation.